# Import multiple text files into excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import multiple text files into 1 excel worksheet. I tried the code below but it does only part of the job I need.
All text files are in the same folder, and have the same name. Therefore, they are: test (1), test (2),..etc.

The goals are: 
import all the text files in only 1 excel worksheet;
 the text files should be paste horizontally: 1 row for each text file in excel. 
Then, the content of the files should be paste in text format. Could you help me in solving this problem?

```
Sub Files()

Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="TEXT Files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)
If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            .Name = "test"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlGeneralFormat)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: are you getting an error ? or the result is not what you expect it to be ?

Comment: Unfortunately the result is different from what I need. Do you have an idea on how to correct?

Comment: Hey guys! Has anyone managed to solve the issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\your_path\")

    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each file In folder.Files

        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
        cl.Value = file.Name
        i = 1

        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            cl.Offset(i, 0).Value = FileText.ReadLine
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        FileText.Close

        Set cl = cl.Offset(0, 1)
    Next file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```